# How to replace the Enchanting alphabet in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft enchanting, the spells are in [Standard Galactic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_Keen#Standard_Galactic_Alphabet), which is clever - but gets old real fast. :) I seem to recall seeing a post about replacing the letters, which I can't find again.

So how can I replace the Enchanting alphabet with readable letters? Is there a texture pack for it? If so, where would I get it, and how to replace it?

Comment: Keep in mind that the names don't actually help – they have nothing to do with the spells themselves. They're mostly just jokes.

Comment: @JakeKing, yeah, I just found that out - sigh...

Comment: What? ...spells?

Comment: @GnomeSlice You been missing out on Minecraft lately?  You can now enchant your items (and brew potions).

Comment: @John, I think GnomeSlice was joking - and I just found out the spell "names" are meaningless, making a translation useless. Also, I didn't bother trying the pre-releases of 1.9, I stayed on 1.8 until the official, final release was complete. Just now learning how spells work. :)

Comment: Same here, but even I knew it *had* spells. :)

Comment: I wasn't joking actually.  I have, in fact, been missing out on Minecraft recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a mod [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/691902-19-pre-3-clear-enchanting-10/) that works for 1.9pre3, but it's just replacing one image file so I'd think it would work with the current version as well.

The [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting) has instructions for replacing the "alternate" font with the "standard" font that I assume should work on any arbitrary version.

Answer (score 3):

Open your `minecraft.jar` (usually found in a folder called `bin`) with WINrar or something. In the font folder there are two `png` files. One called default the other alternative. Rename the one named alternative to default and load up Minecraft. It should change it to the English alphabet.

Comment: Also might help to switch just the makes and keep both of them in. So Alternative becomes default and default becomes Alternative. Sadly thought that doesn't mean you be able to understand it better. Might as well be in a diff language... oh wait it is.